# Get text from CK Editor textarea in JQuery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am using CK Editor in an app.

```
<textarea name="contentDetails" id="contentDetails" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
```

But I can't retrieve text from that textarea. I've tried-

```
 var content= $("#contentDetails").text(); //and also .val() & .html()
```

But `content` variable remains empty.

Any idea?

```
//UPDATE - add my codes below
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace('contentDetails');

$(function () {
    $("#submitcontent").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       var content= $("#contentDetails").text();           
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: try using `.val()` not `.text()`

Comment: When are you calling the function that has the `content` variable?  After the textarea has been populated?

Comment: is content being defined inside an event handler or just somewhere in the code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use:

```
var text = CKEDITOR.instances.contentDetails.getData();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more example (based on **[CKEditor5](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5)**):

```js
let theEditor;

ClassicEditor
  .create(document.querySelector('#contentDetails'))
  .then(editor => {
    theEditor = editor;

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });


function getDataFromTheEditor() {
  return theEditor.getData();
}

document.getElementById('getdata').addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert(getDataFromTheEditor());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/10.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea name="contentDetails" id="contentDetails" rows="10" cols="80">
<p>Here goes the initial content of the editor.</p>
</textarea>
<button id="getdata">Print data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ckeditor will replace your textarea with it's own elements and that is where you will need to get the html from. If you inspect the original textarea you will find it empty, the content is actually elsewhere within a bunch of html generated by the editor. Try using inspect element to find a selector for the element that contains the content that you can use. Make sure your jQuery executes after the editor initializes.

Answer (score 0):

The official [CKEditor jQuery adapter guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery) explains:

```
// Get the editor data.
var data = $( 'textarea.editor' ).val();
// Set the editor data.
$( 'textarea.editor' ).val( 'My new content' );
```

Answer (score -1):

According to official Documentation : [CKEditor Dom Element](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element)

Try

```
textarea = document.getElementById('contentDetails');
textareaNode = new CKEDITOR.dom.element(textarea);
textareaNode.getValue();
```